# how to get dropdown list for the logged in user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity

how to get list in dropdown for the current logged in user

it shows me the list of complete table records from my database

i want it to show my the list of only that belongs to the user logged in

my Controller is below

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,ClinicName,Surgery_ID,Doctor_ID,Patient_ID,Procedure_Code,Appointment_Date,From_Time,To_Time,Status,SMS,Comments")] Schedule schedule)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            schedule.ClinicName = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            db.Schedules.Add(schedule);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        var currentUser = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var schedules = db.Schedules.Where(x => x.ClinicName == currentUser);
        ViewBag.CurrentUser = currentUser;
        // ViewBag.ClinicName = new SelectList(db.AspNetUsers, "Id", "FirstName", schedule.ClinicName);
        ViewBag.Doctor_ID = new SelectList(db.Doctors, "Doctor_ID", "FullName", schedule.Doctor_ID);
        ViewBag.Patient_ID = new SelectList(db.Patients, "Patient_ID", "First_Name", schedule.Patient_ID);
        ViewBag.Surgery_ID = new SelectList(db.Surgeries, "Surgery_ID", "Surgery_Name", schedule.Surgery_ID);
        return View(schedule);
    }
```

and my view is this

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surgery_ID, "Surgery_ID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Surgery_ID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surgery_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Doctor_ID, "Doctor_ID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Doctor_ID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Doctor_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Patient_ID, "Patient_ID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Patient_ID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Patient_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

PLEASE READ MY Question.....i am asking for a LIST of Records to be SHOWN in DROPDOWN LIST made only by the ***LOGGED-IN USER***...............these answers are showing the complete LIST made **by ALL USERS**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the controller

```html
var doctor= db.doctor.ToList().Where(d=>d.UserId==currentUser ); 
ViewBag.DoctorsList = new SelectList(doctor, "Doctor_ID","FullName");
```

in the view

```html
@Html.DropDownList("Doctor_ID",ViewBag.DoctorsList as SelectList,, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Guys........PLEASE READ MY Question.....i am asking for a LIST of Records to be SHOWN in DROPDOWN LIST made only by the LOGGED-IN USER...............these answers are showing the complete LIST made by ALL USERS

Comment: var  doctor= db.doctor.ToList().Where(d=>d.UserId==currentUser  );

ViewBag.DoctorsList = new SelectList(doctor, "Doctor_ID","FullName");

Answer (score 0):

In you control you should have:

```
var DoctorsList = db.Doctors.Select(Doctor=> new { Text = Doctor.FullName, Value =     
    Doctor.Doctor_ID }).OrderBy(Doctor=> Doctor.Doctor_ID );
                    ViewBag.DoctorsList = new SelectList(DoctorsList , "Value", "Text");
```

In view you should have:

```
 @Html.DropDownListmodel => model.Doctor_ID , new SelectList(ViewBag.DoctorsList , "Value", "Text"), "--- Select Doctor---", new {@class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: not working, error on "Value and "Text" i just want to display the list of records made by logged-in user

Comment: so check `db.Doctors` . It should create a list.. is it working? or is it creating a `<list>`? try something like  `db.Doctors.tolist()`

Comment: @Html.DropDownListmodel => model.Doctor_ID , new SelectList(ViewBag.DoctorsList , "Value", "Text"), "--- Select Doctor---", new {@class = "form-control" }) .........................Error in Model area

Comment: What is your model for view?

Comment: put your model for view here

Comment: PLEASE READ MY Question.....i am asking for a LIST of Records to be SHOWN in DROPDOWN LIST made only by the LOGGED-IN USER...............these answers are showing the complete LIST made by ALL USERS

Comment: Be respectful, or DIY!